# How to determine an end of a page before converting html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I have an HTML page that is generated dynamically, based on a specific form. Once an HTML page is generated, it can be converted to PDF using `wkhtmltopdf`.

If the page is too long, `wkhtmltopdf` will automatically split it into multiple pages, but I want to have control over WHERE the split will happen.

I need this because each page will contain specific charts for the specific information that will be displayed on the page and whenever automatic split happens, I sometimes get a chart not being related to the text displayed on the page.

So ideally I want to be able to determine whether the form generated content is too long for 1 page or not and then manually add a new page with controlled content.

To add a new page, I'm basically using the following CSS rule, which works fine:

```
  @media print {
    .new-page {
      page-break-before: always;
    }
  }
```

The application is built in `Laravel` + `Svelte.js` (but I don't think it matters much, because I'm just trying to figure out how to approach the issue in general).

Perhaps I could get some recommendations?

Comment: I think you are on the right path. Take a look at the others CSS rules for controlling page break: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Answer (score 0):

To control where to split your page, you can use the **page-break-after** attribute.

Example :

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but I'm not sure if you read my question. I'd like to be able to determine where to split the page based on the length of content.